# Why is a Qt Signal also linked to the class connect method?

Tags: python, pyside

I'm getting an odd error, and although I can get around it, I'm wondering if anyone knows what's going on here. If I set a signal, and have a method called `connect`, then the signals connect method is overridden with the class one.

It took quite a bit of figuring out as I used the `connect` method to actually link the UI to functions and this is definitely not pythonic behaviour, so my main question is why is this happening?

Here's an example that causes the error `PyQt signal connect() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)`:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    testSignal = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.testSignal.connect(lambda:None)

    def connect(self):
        pass
```

If you give `connect` 3 argument inputs and return `True`, then the signal is happy.

Comment: That's just the way pyside works. If you think it's wrong, there's no point reporting it here: you need to take it up with the pyside devs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it using:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    testSignal = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.testSignal.connect(self.debug)

    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("got", args, "and", kwargs)
```

so you can see, what values are passed to your signal hander `debug`.

Comment: The issue isn't what the signals returning, it's that I can't have `MainWindow.connect` or it overwrites `QtCore.Signal.connect`, which seems really weird Python behaviour